# fimse sem SE correspondente

Tags: visualg

Estou tentando rodar esse código, porém na linha 40 no fimse, fica apresentando o erro:  fimse sem SE correspondente

```
Algoritmo "semnome"
// Disciplina   : [Linguagem e Lógica de Programação]
// Professor   : Antonio Carlos Nicolodi 
// Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
// Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
// Data atual  : 23/11/2019
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
idade, obrigatorio, facultativo, naoeleitor,cont, i: inteiro

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
escreva("Quantas pessoas quer cadastrar?")

leia(cont)

enquanto i <> cont faca

  escreval("digite a idade do morador")

  leia (idade)

  se ((idade >=18) e (idade <= 69)) entao

    obrigatorio = obrigatorio + 1

 fimse


 se ((idade = 16) ou (idade = 17) ou (idade >=70)) entao

  facultativo = facultativo + 1

 fimse

 se (idade <16) entao

 naoeleitor = nao eleitor + 1

fimse

i = i + 1

fimenquanto

escreval("A quantidade de eleitores obrigatorios e", obrigatorio)

escreval ("A quantidade de eleitores facultativos e", facultativo)

escreval ("A quantidade de nao eleitore e", naoeleitor)

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Qual dessas linhas é a linha 40?

Comment: se ((idade >=18) e (idade <= 69)) entao

    obrigatorio = obrigatorio + 1

 fimse -- essa

Comment: O símbolo igual (`=`) é o operador de comparação e não o comando de atribuição. Aqui: `naoeleitor = nao eleitor + 1`creio que não exista esse espaço após o `nao`. Faltou inicializar a variável `i`com zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Estou tentando rodar esse código, porém na linha 40 no fimse, fica apresentando o erro: fimse sem SE correspondente

Em testes, não apresentou o mesmo erro... tanto na versão 2.5, tanto na versão 3.0.6.5 do VisualG. Basicamente o erro está no "símbolo" usado para "atribuição de valores". Segue:

#### Comandos de atribuição no VisualG

Existem 2: ou `<-` ou `:=`

Modo incorreto:

> `obrigatorio = obrigatorio + 1`

Modos válidos:

`obrigatorio <- obrigatorio + 1`
ou
`obrigatorio := obrigatorio + 1`

Adendo: o comando `=` é utilizado para "comparações".

#### Inicialização de variáveis

No VisualG, as variáveis meio que já são* inicializadas automaticamente, ou seja: as variáveis numéricas ficam com 0; os caracteres ficam com ""; os do tipo lógico ficam com `FALSO` etc.

Mas, como boa prática, seria recomendado reforçar... tanto porque essa característica (de "autoinicialização") não é comum em linguagens de programação; e fica mais explícito para quem está analisando o código.

Segue um exemplo baseado no seu código:

```
algoritmo "Eleitores"
// Disciplina  :
// Professor   :
// Descrição   :
// Autor(a)    : Jéssica Almeida
// Data atual  : 23/11/2019
var
   idade: inteiro
   obrigatorio, facultativo, naoEleitor: inteiro
   cont, total: inteiro

inicio
   escreva("Quantas pessoas quer cadastrar?")
   leia(total)

   cont <- 0 //apesar de ser inicializado automaticamente com 0, não custa nada!
   enquanto (cont < total) faca
      escrevaL("Digite a idade do morador")
      leia (idade)

      se ((idade >= 18) e (idade < 70)) entao
         obrigatorio <- obrigatorio + 1
      fimSe

      se (((idade >= 16) ou (idade <= 17)) ou (idade >= 70)) entao
         facultativo <- facultativo + 1
      fimSe

      se (idade < 16) entao
         naoEleitor <- naoEleitor + 1
      fimSe

      cont <- cont + 1
   fimEnquanto

   escrevaL("A quantidade de eleitores obrigatorios é ", obrigatorio:1)
   escrevaL("A quantidade de eleitores facultativos é ", facultativo:1)
   escrevaL("A quantidade de não eleitores é ", naoeleitor:1)
fimAlgoritmo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]